# Which Netbeans 8.2 project files should be committed to version control for C++ project?

Tags: c++, netbeans, development-environment

Should this Netbeans (C++) project file:

```
nbproject/configurations.xml
```

be stored within version control/which ones should/shouldn't?

I am currently the only person using Netbeans but I worry what would happen if a second person was modifying that file (via their IDE), submitting and then me pulling/using that?

I have Google'd but answers appear to be out-of-date now.

Netbeans version is 8.2

Comment: [1] This is only for C/C++ projects, right? If so, you might consider refining your question, since it is very broad (too broad?) as it stands. NetBeans supports Java, JavaScript, PHP, C/C++, Fortran, etc. Specify the language(s) you are concerned about. [2] What version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: @skomisa thanks, I have edited it to reflect C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had good experiences using whatever .gitignore entries are stored on [Github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/NetBeans.gitignore). This is not some random repo, but one of GitHub's own that accepts community contributions. Following the link will show 9 contributors to this specific .gitignore for NetBeans and that it was last updated in Dec. 2018.

It appears that the configuration file you're asking about would and likely should be placed under version control.